# Add new points into a shapefile iteratively with PyQGIS

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, create

I would like to create a filtered layer with the same attributes than an other layer, based on a condition. Moreover, I would like to fill in the shapefile iteratively when my condition is verified.

I tried to do so but my new shapefile contains only one point, when it should contain more. How I can fix it to get the whole lines into one new shp layer?

This part of script below is contained into :

```
For value1 in DatesHours:
 [...]

 For value2 in RefValues :
  [...]

  writer1= QgsVectorFileWriter(dir + "/Selection1.shp", "CP1250", provider.fields(), provider.geometryType(), provider.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
  writer2 = QgsVectorFileWriter(dir +"/Selection2b.shp", "CP1250", provider.fields(), provider.geometryType(), provider.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
  outelem=QgsFeature()

  for feature in macouche.getFeatures():

   true=0
   attri1=feature.attributes()

   if attri1[0] == value2 :
    ecart= datetime.datetime.strptime(value1,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') - datetime.datetime.strptime(feature['DATE3'],'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

    if ecart < zero:
     ecart= datetime.datetime.strptime(feature['DATE3'],'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') - datetime.datetime.strptime(value1,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
     if ecart_minN > ecart :
      ecart_minN=ecart
      DHp=feature['DATE3']
      true = 1
    else:
     if ecart_minP > ecart :
      ecart_minP=ecart
      DHn=feature['DATE3']
      true = 1

   if true == 1 :
    outelem.setGeometry(feature.geometry())
    outelem.setAttributes(feature.attributes())
    writer1.addFeature(write(outelem,feature))
```

Comment: Your `if true == 1` (at the end of the snippet) seems to be on the same indent level than your `for feature in macouche.getFeatures()`. If that's not a copy/paste error, that would explain your issue.

Comment: I am sorry it is. The if true == 1 is on the same indent level as if attri1[0] == value2.

Comment: Ok, I corrected the indent in your post.